# No audio when connecting one plus z2 earbuds to fedora 35

Tags: fedora, bluetooth, blueman

I recently bought OnePlus Z2 earbuds.

While I am easily able to connect them with my phone, even when I am connecting with my laptop which runs fedora, the audio comes from the laptop's speaker and not through the earbuds.

The bluetooth settings show the type of device to be unknown instead of headset.

[image: The bluetooth settings show the type of device to be unknown instead of headset.]

The output audio settings only show the speakers as a source of output.

[image: The output audio settings only show the speakers as a source of output.]

And blueman software also shows the type of earbuds to be miscellaneous instead of headset.

[image: And blueman software also shows the type of earbuds to be miscellaneous instead of headset.]

I dont think there is a problem with my bluetooth as I am able to connect with other headphones or earbuds successfully without any issue.

How can I fix this so that I can connect my earbuds with my laptop.

Comment: If you connect via `blueman`, does it work then?

Comment: Hello @rickhg12hs

No it doesnt. Blueman treats them as miscellaneous devices instead of headset.

Comment: Does a factory reset of the earbuds help?

Comment: Hi @rickhg12hs

No it didnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same exact problem. I solved it by:

```
ControllerMode = bredr
```

in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

from: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=270465

I am using pipewire, so if the above doesn't work, here are the [instructions for pipewire on Ubuntu](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/pipewire-replace-pulseaudio-ubuntu-2204/), I'm pretty new to Linux so I'm not sure how easily that will translate to your distro: